# how to change the publishing rate of /fix topic in nmea_navsat_driver package

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In nmea_navsat_driver package [nmea_navsat-driver](http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver).
I have noticed that the publishing rate of /fix is about 1 Hz, but I want to make it faster than 1 Hz.
In its python code, it does not specify  the rospy.Rate(), I want know how to change rate the /fix topic.

actually I have tried to add rate = rosy.Rate() for the while loop, but it did not work.

is there anybody who can help me!! thank u!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282140/how-to-change-the-publishing-rate-of-/fix-topic-in-nmea_navsat_driver-package/) by [wawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33616/wawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33616/wawa/) on 2018-02-08**:
GPS = serial.Serial(port=serial_port, baudrate=serial_baud, timeout=2)
driver = libnmea_navsat_driver.driver.RosNMEADriver()
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
data = GPS.readline().strip()
try:
driver.add_sentence(data, frame_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The driver you have linked to publishes one fix for each sentence received. If you want more faster fix updates you will need to update your GPS settings to output NMEA updates more frequently.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33616/wawa/) on 2018-02-10**:
ok. in the data sheet of GPS, it writes that I can change the updating rate of NMEA, dose the updating rate of NMEA means the output frequency?